# Best graph type for clusters of web requests in time period

Tags: python, apache, logging, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm writing a short Python script to try and visualise some of our Apache logs using matplotlib, to get an idea of the kinds of requests being made, and the users doing so.

Parsing the logs into a DB format for easy querying was simple enough, however I'm currently wondering what the best kind of graph to use would be if I'm looking for clusters of data - if say, one user is performing a lot of requests one after another with different timestamps, for example, this may present a fairly constant, but low line on a line graph or scatter diagram, but I'd like to make it more visually obvious that the user is making regular requests during a period of time.

If it was a pure count of the number of hits a user is making, it wouldn't be an issue, as a bar graph would suffice, but I'm at a loss as to how I can relate those hits around a time period, without specifying ranges of time periods in my initial query.

Anyone unfamiliar with the graph types matplotlib/pyplot offers can see a range of them here: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Suggestions from any of the data visualisation veterans out there are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bubbles to indicate how many user counts over an interval in your timeline. Bigger bubble means more hits. Rank your users based on total hits so the most active ones appear first. It's kinda like bar chart but you use bubbles to indicate counts.

Something like this:

http://neuralengr.com/asifr/journals/

Comment: Nice, that could work quite nicely - now to figure out how to get matplotlib to make them!